# What are the SNMP MIBs for Cisco IPSLA ICMP echo

Tags: cisco, snmp, icmp

I have two ipsla operations set up:

```
ipsla
 operation 10
  type icmp echo
   source address 10.0.0.1
   destination address 10.0.2
   frequency 30
 operation 11
  type udp jitter
   tos 128
   source address 10.0.0.3
   destination address 10.0.0.4
   destination port 10001
   frequency 30
```

With operation 11, I can SNMP walk [1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.5.2.1](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.5.2.1&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT) to get the values that match with `sh ipsla stats 11`.  However, I cannot find the MIB to walk to get the values for `sh ipsla stats 10`.

The router is running **Cisco IOS XR Software (Cisco ASR9K Series),  Version 4.2.3[Default]**

What are the MIBs for an IPSLA operation configured to use ICMP echo?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in the RTT stats?  Or do you just want to get "up/down" information for an IPSLA via SNMP?

Comment: I'm interested in RTT, connection status and jitter (where possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the MIBs.  For the IPSLA types, `udp jitter`, `icmp echo` and `icmp path-echo`, the RTT and connection status are stored in the [rttMonLatestRttOperEntry](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.10.1) table

- [rttMonLatestRttOperCompletionTime](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.10.1.1) has the average RTT
- [rttMonLatestRttOperSense](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.10.1.2) has the connection status (ok/disconected etc.)

  - [List of values](https://support.ipmonitor.com/mibs/CISCO-RTTMON-MIB/item.aspx?tid=RttResponseSense) for [RttResponseSense](https://support.ipmonitor.com/mibs/CISCO-RTTMON-MIB/item.aspx?tid=RttResponseSense)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have no results because your ipsla operation 10 is malformed. You should change destination address from `10.0.02` to `10.0.0.2`.

I think this is why you cannot get stats from operation 10.

Comment: Actually that was a typo when I was entering the question here.  I changed the IPs from the actual ones we use.