# Can I get ip-sla's destination IP address via snmp?

Tags: snmp

(Excuse my lack of networking knowledge as I am mainly a developer)

Is it possible to snmpalk to get a list of all ip-sla's destination ip address via **snmp**?

( **Router**:  Cisco IOS XR Software (ASR9K), Version 7.1.3 )

I have been searching for an OID that returns me this list but I was not succesfull.

Any advices, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Care to mention the router model you're referring to? Since IP SLAs are no standard (IETF) functionality it's at least vendor specific.

Comment: Thanks, I have just added the info.

Comment: I don't have an ASR to test this on, though I suspect you can gather the destination IPs of the configured ip sla using the information in the answer of this question: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18078/what-are-the-snmp-mibs-for-cisco-ipsla-icmp-echo

Also, SNMP MIBs for Cisco software is usually not publicly available (in my experience) and need to open a TAC case with Cisco to have them provide the documentation.